# How to make a post request with a image file using form-data in ionic-3

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, httpclient

My backend is a simple **Laravel API**, and my API is working properly when I use PostMan application.

I use form data to post my request without any header. it is 100% worked but when I am trying on my ionic code its not working 
[image: This is postman request]

-- this is the error --

[image: this is the error massage]

---this is my backend code error showing in line no 55:
[image]

```
selectphoto(){

const options: CameraOptions = {
  quality: 50,
  destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
  sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
  saveToPhotoAlbum: false }

this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
  // imageData is either a base64 encoded string or a file URI
  // If it's base64 (DATA_URL): base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
  this.image = normalizeURL(imageData);
 }, (err) => {
  // Handle error
 });}

 onSubmit(form:NgForm){

  console.log('img' , this.image);
  this.actorBestMovie = form.value.actorBestMovie;
  this.actorCountry = form.value.actorCountry;
  this.actorFirstMovie = form.value.actorFirstMovie;
  this.actorImdbBestMovie = form.value.actorImdbBestMovie;
  this.actorName = form.value.actorName;
  this.actorpost();
  form.reset()  
}

 actorpost() {

  let headers = new Headers();
  headers.append("Accept", "application/json");
  let body = new FormData();
  body.append('file',this.image);
  body.append('name',this.actorName); 
  body.append('country',this.actorCountry );
  body.append('first_movie',this.actorFirstMovie);
  body.append('best_movie',this.actorBestMovie);
  body.append('imdb_best_movie',this.actorImdbBestMovie); 

this.http.post("http://localhost/slreview-api/public/api/actors",body,{headers: headers })
  .map(res => res.json())
  .subscribe(
    data => {
      console.log("data => ", data);
    },
    error => {
      console.log('Error => ', error);
    },
    () => {
      console.log('Completed!');
      this.presentToast();
    }
  );}
```

I want to post my data though post request 
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Change the appending order of parameters and append image file as the last parameter to `FormData` like below.

```
  let body = new FormData();
  body.append('name',this.actorName); 
  body.append('country',this.actorCountry );
  body.append('first_movie',this.actorFirstMovie);
  body.append('best_movie',this.actorBestMovie);
  body.append('imdb_best_movie',this.actorImdbBestMovie);
  body.append('file',this.image);
```

Comment: its still not working.. error in image file request  this is the error ----->{message: "Call to a member function store() on null",…}
exception: "Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError"
file: "C:\xampp\htdocs\slreview-api\app\Http\Controllers\ActorController.php"
line: 55
message: "Call to a member function store() on null"   ---->  the error line is my requested image  file in my backend